# How to do Sequential Subtraction of a series, reducing from initial Total to zero, subtracting from previous cell with current row value

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction

I have this input table and the total amount 153876.01

| Index | AMOUNT | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18661.02 | 135214.99 |
| 2 | 1365.44 |  |
| 3 | 2821.91 |  |
| 4 | 2821.91 |  |
| ... | ... |  |
| 75 | 227.57 |  |
| 76 | 188.13 |  |
| 77 | 141.10 |  |
| 78 | 84.96 |  |
| 79 | 47.08 |  |

I need to compute the `Balance`, as below:

|  | Imports | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18661.02 | 135214.99 |
| 1 | 1365.44 | 133849.55 |
| 2 | 2821.91 | 131027.64 |
| 3 | 2821.91 | 128205.73 |
| 4 | 2548.82 | 125656.91 |
| .. | ... | ... |
| 73 | 227.57 | 461.27 |
| 74 | 188.13 | 273.14 |
| 75 | 141.10 | 132.04 |
| 76 | 84.96 | 47.08 |
| 77 | 47.08 | 0.00 |

[78 rows x 2 columns]

A better explanation would be:

This is what I am doing right now and able to compute the `Balance` column:

```
def somefunc(row):
    print(row.name)
    if row.name != 0:
        print(row.name, df_in['Balance'][row.name-1], row['AMOUNT'])
        df_in.at[row.name, 'Balance'] = df_in['Balance'][row.name-1] - row['AMOUNT']
df_in.apply(somefunc, axis=1)
```

I am looking for a solution that is right and far better than this one and which is also correct while using pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) your initial total:

```
total = 153876.01
# or if the final Balance should be 0
total = df['AMOUNT'].sum()

df['Balance'] = df['AMOUNT'].cumsum().rsub(total)
```

If the final Balance is 0, you can also compute a reverse `cumsum` and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), which might be even more efficient to compute:

```
df['Balance'] = df.loc[::-1, 'AMOUNT'].cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
      AMOUNT    Balance
 0  18661.02  135214.99
 1   1365.44  133849.55
 2   2821.91  131027.64
...
77     47.08       0.00
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mozway. You have already given me the next problem solution along with the original problem. And appreciate your quick response. Thanks :)